# "main" has not been registered

Tags: react-native, expo

**Error:**
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props = props')
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:172:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:204:6 in guardedLoadModule
at http://127.0.0.1:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:159403:3 in global code

Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
  at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
  at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:172:19 in handleException
  at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
  at node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError

**App JS File:**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import MainScreen from './screens/mainScreen';

const { Navigator, Screen } = createStackNavigator();

export default class App extends Component(){
  render(){
    return(
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Navigator>
          <Screen name="mainScreen" component={MainScreen}></Screen>
        </Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

**mainScreen File**

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import Input from '../components/Input';
import { styles } from "../styles/style";

export default class MainScreen extends Component() {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.header}>
          <View style={{ flex: 0.6, paddingTop: 20 }}>
            <Text style={styles.headerText}>Find Your Next Trip!</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ flex: 0.35, alignItems: 'flex-end', paddingTop: 20 }}>
            <Image source={require("../assets/images/default.jpg")} style={styles.headerImage}></Image>
          </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
        <View style={styles.textCenter}>
          <Input placeholder="search"/>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
          <View style={styles.imageView}>
            <Image source={require("../assets/images/amsterdam.jpeg")} style={styles.image} />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.imageView}>
            <Image source={require("../assets/images/moscow.jpeg")} style={styles.image} />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: red screen error message on React Native app]

Comment: Your extends syntax is incorrect, you should not be calling Component like that (i.e. extends Component()) - remove the function call and make it extends Component instead.

Answer (score 1):

i got this case too yesterday.

i solve with i check `@react-navigation/native` and `@react-navigation/stack` version in json package and i get my react navigation not the latest version.

- i install the newest version of react navigation
- for `{createStackNavigator}` i import from`@react-navigation/native-stack` not `@react-navigation/stack`
- restart expo
- solved

Answer (score 0):

I got such a problem after installing react native svg, it had to do with the version installed being too new or something. I got feedback after closing the server and starting it up again